# Getting 'TOKEN_INVALID' error on discord.js while token is acutally valid

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot using javascript but when I try to run it , I get the error "[Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'". I double checked to see if my token is correct and I even regenerated it for a few times but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN);
```

And here is my .env file:

```
CLIENT_TOKEN='token'
```

Note: Im new to javascript so try to explain it noob friendly please.

Comment: Have you logged `process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN` to confirm the `.env` file has been properly pointed to? Try `console.log(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN)`

Comment: Yes but it still says 'TOKEN_INVALID'.

Comment: Log it and compare your token to the token in the developer portal, you may have reset your token in the developer portal on accident without updating the value in your env file.

Comment: In .env, make sure not to surround it in "" or ''

Comment: Solved it. Apparently I regenerated the token without changing it in the code. I was so desperate that I forgot to change it. Im dumb. Sorry for wasting ur time guys.

Comment: @ZyptaR Also just saying but **ALWAYS** put that `client.login` at the very last line of your discord bot code. Also, put your comment as an answer and then mark it as the best answer to close the thread.